# In-memory scanning of files, ideally using ClamAV

Tags: java, antivirus

We are implementing an enterprise application with a heavy focus on security, which includes the uploading of files. These files need to be virus scanned, but also need to be encrypted.

The current process is that the files are uploaded and then streamed - through an encrypter - to a temporary storage area on disk. The virus-scanner is then called and the files are decrypted on the fly, streamed through to ClamAV via a socket - and then the virus-status returned from the socket.

The problem is that ClamAV seems to write to a temporary area on disk before scanning, which means unencrypted, potentially-sensitive data on the file-system.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Possibly by configuring ClamAV to scan in-memory only (my Google search yielded no results), or maybe some alternative suggestions?

Comment: Couldn't you just mount this filesystem with a TrueCrypt container? So the applications writes to a secured space on disk.

Comment: Also, unless you have encrypted swap, then the 'memory' may get written to disk. And an attacker could freeze the memory to get it's contents.

Comment: I think the memory aspect is important as well. Tha k you. Actually, I appreciate everyone's comments. Thank you all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming here that you are using clamd since you are talking to it via a socket not clamscan the cli tool.

In that case you can configure it via the TemporaryDirectory directive in your clamd.conf to point to an encrypted filesystem for temp storage using something like dm-crypt (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedFilesystemHowto) - I hope this helps.

Reference from man 5 clamd.conf:

```
   TemporaryDirectory STRING
          Optional path to the global temporary directory.
          Default: system specific (usually /tmp or /var/tmp).
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a good example:

Java API to Detect Virus Using ClamAV Antivirus

http://nsinfra.blogspot.ca/2011/06/java-api-to-detect-virus-using-clamav.html

This post describes the approach of scanning files to detect trojans, viruses, malware and other malicious threats using java APIs.

Following items have been covered:
  About ClamAV antivirus
  Instructions to install ClamAV antivirus on Linux machine
  Approach to scan file using ClamAV Java API to detect virus

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing I can imagine is using a ram disk.

Maybe you should check if ClamAV has a more sophisticated API for such a task.